# pthread_join - target thread is terminated but not detached

Tags: pthreads

I was going through following link to understand pthreads:
[pthreads information](http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/%7Edheerajb/Pthreads/Document/Pthreads_Information.html)

The pthread_join() function description is confusing me:

> If the target thread is already terminated, but not yet detached, the subroutine returns immediately.
>
> The target thread is automatically detached after all joined threads have been woken up.

Could not understand these 2 statements

Comment: What exactly you don't understand?

Comment: To be fair, the second of these sentences is incomprehensible. I'd recommend reading useful documentation like [manpages](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_join) or the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) instead of this garbage.

Comment: @arrowd I didn't understand the state 'terminated but not detached' . When will thread be in this state ? And the second statement is completely confusing. join will cause detached ? All joined threads are woken ?